# Kotlin select from list

Tags: kotlin, generics, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a situation like

```
class Ball {}
class WhiteBall : Ball {}
class BlackBall : Ball {}
 
val listOfBalls: List<Ball> = ...
```

How elegantly get first balls from the list/array
while, for example, i've taken <= 5 WHITE BALLS?

I know only that way:

```
val NMAX = 5
var balls = 0
val listOfBalls: List<Ball> = ...
return listOfBalls.takeWhile { ball ->
   if (ball is WhiteBall) balls++
   return@takeWhile balls <= NMAX + 1
}
```

*// example selection
// B,B,B,B,B, W, W, W, B,B,...,B, W, W*

UPDATE:
It seems I'm not clearly described what I want to select.
Let's assume we have 2 types of entities - `AlbumTitle` and `AlbumPicture`, which form the `listOf<AlbumItem>(...)`.

A plain list contains this objects in some order, for example

1. AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture**, AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture**, **AlbumPicture**
2. AlbumTitle, AlbumTitle, AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture, AlbumPicture**

I want to select all objects in the same order, but stop filling my new list
when I take 2 pictures.

So I should filter

1. AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture**, AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture**
2. AlbumTitle, AlbumTitle, AlbumTitle, **AlbumPicture, AlbumPicture**

Comment: `listOfBalls.filter { it is WhiteBall }.take(5)`

Comment: @Tenfour04 that's not what I want, I'm getting all elements but counting only White Balls.
When count of White Balls will be five, I must stop

Comment: I don't think it can be streamlined very much. You can eliminate `NMAX`  if you start `balls` at 5 and count down. `return@takeWhile` can be omitted since the last line of a lambda is implicitly returned.

Comment: Use [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html), they don't run unless terminal operation is triggered, and will do the same thing as you want. Check the diagram at the end for better visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Elegantly (without eagerly creating intermediate collections):

```
listOfBalls.asSequence()
.filterIsInstance<WhiteBall>()
.take(5)
.toList()
```

See [Sequences in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sequences.html).
Also, a helpful video from [Android Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77hfjIYwouw).